# Using Local AD credentials in Sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, active-directory, active-directory-import

Currently I am working in Sharepoint online. Am in a situation of testing audiences and security permissions. For testing these multiple accounts are needed, but unfortunately only one account is available.

So here is my question. *Is there any way to use the local AD credentials in Sharepoint online just by pointing it directly to use our AD server(like in on-premise). And we don't want to sync our AD with Azure AD service. Is this really possible?* If not then I need to convince my higher authorities based on your answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to use On Premise AD without syncing it to Azure AD.

Comment: You can perform sync and then once you are done with your testing, you can remove those from online environment. Check this MS [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2619062). Better need to collaborate with your higher authorities though !!

Answer (score 0):

no there is no other option. If you want to work with On-Premises AD accounts, you must them synchronize into AAD in Online environment.